# restrict css affecting outside div

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to make my own webmail front end. The only part I am having problems with is rendering HTML emails. I don't want to use iframes so I attempted to use `<style scoped />`. This worked successfully for some but when I opened a message with inline CSS it would not show any of the message content in Firefox

> Error Console reports:
>   "Warning: Unexpected end of file while searching for closing } of invalid rule set."

This is the only error that reported. Is there any way to limit a external sourced content to a div without affecting any other CSS on the page? Can this be done with jQuery as the content is loaded with ajax?

Viper

Comment: Css can only work for all email boxes ir you use inline css. You can show your HTML code, please?

Comment: Put the entire file code on pastebin or jsfiddle and post the link.

Comment: I have added a pastebin of the problem part http://pastebin.com/UbHMWzT9 the content in <div id="mailcol2> is loaded by ajax but the section between <style scoped="scoped">...</style> is not displaying on the browser. FF or IE.

Answer (score 1):

1) As of now, the `scoped` attribute is only [supported in Firefox](http://caniuse.com/#search=scoped), that's why you should by no means rely on it to work properly.

2) The html you are trying to render is invalid (hence the error about the missing bracket) and for that reason does not render correctly. I guess you have no direct control over the content. So, that Firefox fails to diregard the faulty css and render the remaining part of the html is nothing you could do about (asides from filing a bug report).

3) In terms of restriction your safest bet probably would be to use an iframe since it provides a natural sandbox for the content inside and prevents error from leaking to the outside document. Otherwise you would have to parse the HTML and check for validity. It is possible, but trust me, you don't really want to do this.